# Struggling with Muscle cramps when in water

Tags: swimming, muscle-cramps

I am not a very good swimmer. I don't swim regularly either.
When I swim and relax for an less than an hour, I start getting cramps, specifically in Toes.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Hi WedaPashi! I see this question is up for re-opening. I'm voting to keep it closed. It's almost an exact duplicate of [another question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7289/) you wrote a few months after this one, which already has useful answers. It's nothing personal, but I don't see the purpose in re-opening this, especially since it would likely be closed very quickly as a duplicate.

Comment: @Sue: That makes sense. Just in case if you are assuming that I voted to re-open this, I haven't! :-)

Comment: Thanks for understanding. I didn't mean to sound blunt! I actually didn't think it was you who voted to re-open! (By the way, I had already upvoted it, which must have happened pretty quickly after you posted it. I upvoted the other a long time ago too, and the answers!)  I hope you've been enjoying swimming more comfortably. :)